# Login Header does not work

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to code a login-system, but I've got a problem with the login:

As you join the webpage you get to

```
../?p=Login
```

As you press the Login-button then you should be send to

```
../?p=index
```

**But the header should be**

```
../?a=loggedin
```

because the standard is

```
Includes/index.php
```

The PHP-code in index:

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = htmlspecialchars($_GET['p']);
}   else {
    $p = "index";
}

include 'Includes/' . $p . ".php";
```

In the `Includes/index.php` is **`a`** output if a equals loggedin:

```
if(isset($_GET['a'])) {
if($_GET['a'] == "loggedin") {
  echo('<div class="Password-true"> Du hast dich erfolgreich angemeldet. 
</div>');
}
}
```

I think the problem might be in the login code but as I don't know where 
the problem is, I inserted all of the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = password_hash(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']), 
PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

$login_statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_users WHERE username 
LIKE :username OR email LIKE :username");
$login_statement->bindParam("username", $username);
$login_statement->execute();
$user = $login_statement->fetch();

if($user != null) {
  if(isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
  }
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
  header("Location: /?a=loggedin");
  } else {
  echo('<div class="login-false"> Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht 
  überein. </div>');
  }
  }

  <div class="login">
  <div class="login-header">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <hr size="3" />
  </div>
  <div class="login-content">
  <form method="post" action="/?p=Login">
  <h3> Benutzername / E-Mail </h3>
  <input type="text" class="datainput" name="username" style="height: 30px; 
  padding-left: 5px;" required placeholder="Nutzername oder E-Mail"  /><br>
  <br>

  <h3> Passwort</h3>
  <input type="password" class="datainput" name="password" style="height: 
  30px; padding-left: 5px;" required placeholder="Passwort" /><br><br><br>
   <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Login" style="height: 30px; width: 100px;" />
   </form>
  </div>
    <div class="login-footer">
   <hr size="3" />
     Fülle alle Felder aus, um dich anzumelden.
 </div>
 </div>
```

Finally I want to add, that I used [a tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCtJyU81FPk) and I use Bootstrap and jQuery.

My website is: http://mysticsouls.developed-media.de

(It isn't nice yet).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have a remote file inclusion vulnerability ! please replace replace `$p = htmlspecialchars($_GET['p']);` by `$p = basename($_GET['p']);`

Comment: Please do not forget to accept my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header()` will not work if the headers were already sent... *aka* if some code/html is displayed before this part is executed.

An alternative would be to echo some JavaScript. Since you have jquery in there I thought you might be open to an alternative ;)

`<script>window.location = '/?a=loggedin'</script>`

From what I can see your code has some **serious security issues**. You should work on a local copy first, I'd even go as far as disabling the live version... For now...

Comment: Glad I could help !
Never trust user input... `htmlspecialchars` is not the solution to everything :P please do not forget to accept my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wanting this for a url:
/?p=index&a=loggedin

Then you can $_GET both p and a from this.  Otherwise, can you clarify more?